# How do I change one image to another upon clicking on a button

Tags: c#

I have 2 images, using the `else-if` method, how do I make it so that when I click on image A, it turns to image B and if its image B, turn back to image A? Here is my codes:

```
private void Smalltubbutton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap1 =
      WindowsFormsApplication21.Properties.Resources.smalltub)
   {
         System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap1 = 
                        WindowsFormsApplication21.Properties.Resources.GRAYSCALEsmalltub;
   }
   else
   {
     System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap1 = 
                    WindowsFormsApplication21.Properties.Resources.smalltub      
   }
}
```

Comment: This question is too basic. Find a working example (I assume WinForms?) and try that out first. B.t.w, the if statement has an assignment operator (=); this should be '=='.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10468284/1648849) question with similar issue.

Comment: you have to play with the visibility property.

Comment: Instead of checking the bitmap property it's better to use a simple boolean flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a PictureBox and change the image property with your proper image and change a boolean property or variable each time you click on that.

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if (flag)
           pictureBox1.Image = WindowsFormsApplication21.Properties.Resources.GRAYSCALEsmalltub;
      else
           pictureBox1.Image = WindowsFormsApplication21.Properties.Resources.smalltub;
      flag=!flag;
}
```

I hope this would solve your problem. Good Luck.

Answer (score 2):

You could do that someway like this:

```
private bool flag;
private void Smalltubbutton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap1;

    if (flag)
    {
        bitmap1 = WindowsFormsApplication21.Properties.Resources.GRAYSCALEsmalltub;
    }
    else
    {
        bitmap1 = WindowsFormsApplication21.Properties.Resources.smalltub      
    }

    flag = !flag;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, when I click the button, nothing changes, I copied the exact same thing as you did though.

Comment: @LokeBoon you shouldn't only copy my answer without looking through that at all. Main idea of that was to use flag to save state.

Comment: sorry but i'm quite new to programming so I have no idea what flag or state is.. I did look through and tried other alternatives but to no avail..